# For Selenium, how to migrate to using WebDriver for HttpCommandProcessor?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, deprecated

I recently noticed that the HttpCommandProcessor has been marked as deprecated, but there doesn't seem to be anything that replicates its functionality that isn't deprecated.

In particular the WebDriverCommandProcessor does not have a browser start command, and the start(String s) method just throws an UnsupportedOperationException. I am not sure about what Selenium has added to replace these functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `HttpCommandProcessor` class, I'm assuming you're also using the `DefaultSelenium` class as your basic Selenium API. That's using Selenium RC. The entirety of Selenium RC is deprecated, and has been replaced by Selenium WebDriver. Yes, WebDriver is a different API than RC, but the guidance from the Selenium project is that this deprecation has been coming for at least the last three years, at the time of this writing.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way to migrate from the HttpCommandProcessor to anything right now?

Comment: Not to anything supported, no. Furthermore, there **won't** be anything to migrate to, and still use the RC API. This is to be expected. You could use the `WebDriverBackedSelenium` class, which instantiates a `WebDriverCommandProcessor`, but this is intended to be an interim method to help you migrate your code to using WebDriver, /not/ a permanent solution or workaround.